Google Cloud Run failing with Google OAuth2 due to redirect_uri_mismatch
I've got a simple Python application running as a Google Cloud Run service, just to test login with Google OAuth2.  The application works very well in my development environment on localhost, but when I deploy with Google Cloud Run it fails due to redirect_uri_mismatch, and of course Google's useless error messages don't tell me what redirect URI it's looking for.
Here are the error details:

and here's the registration code from the application:
`
root = 'https://helloworld-lrbsxicfna-uw.a.run.app'
# Configure OAuth
oauth = OAuth(app)
google = oauth.register(
    name='google',
    client_id='<redacted>',
    client_secret='<redacted>',
    authorize_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    access_token_url='https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token',
    redirect_uri=f'{root}/oauth2callback',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'email'},
    server_metadata_url = 'https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'
)

`
The callback route is given by @app.route('/oauth2callback'):
And I'm running on a standard port : app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
And I've registered the callback properly:

When I run locally on http://localhost:8080 it runs fine, with route = 'http://localhost:8080' and app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port-8080) being the only changes.
But when I deploy to Cloud Run it fails, obscurely.  The only thing I can think of is that Cloud Run is overwriting the callback URL, but what the value is I've no idea.  And I can't adjust at runtime because the callback URL has to be registered statically on the consent screen.
Anyone faced this issue?
A solution is to say the hell with CloudRun and just run a minimal VM, but this is really ridiculous.
And, yes, I've gone over all the troubleshooting steps.  AFAICT the routes I've entered in the code and the credentials screen match.  So sending generic advice from the troubleshooting page won't help...I've tried that.

You can typically see the used redirect URI in the initial redirect to the Google Account service, and sometimes you need to manually override it in the code, so it matches the public redirect URI. It should always be a HTTPS link, otherwise you will have cookie problems.

Thanks.  Do I look for this in the logs, in the browser header?  This is the "request details" I got from Google:  redirect_uri=http://helloworld-lrbsxicfna-uw.a.run.app/oauth2callback flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

And that isn't a valid URI (space between callback and flowName...and I tried putting a question mark in

When you trigger a signin in your appliation, you are redirected to https://accounts.google.com/v3/signin/identifier?continue=https%253A%252F%252Fmail.google.com.....  Check the complete URL here.. it incudes the redirect URL that your application presents to Google. It must match exactly what you have registered earlier.

@RickMcGeer, does above comments helped to solve your issue? Are you still facing issue?

@RickMcGeer have you solved this issue?

Thanks, this information was useful, I noticed that my app uses a redirect to http://.
